# Python: why does multiprocessing apply threading instead of multiple processors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am using the inspyred library for genetic algorithms. I have the following configuration:

```
def distance(route, distances):
    totalDistance = 0

    for idx, customer in enumerate(route):
        if (idx < len(route) - 1):
            distance = distances[customer][route[idx + 1]]
            totalDistance += distance

    return totalDistance


def evaluator(candidates, args):

    data = args['data']
    distances = data.distances

    fitness = []

    for candidate in candidates:
        tot_distance = 0
        for index, route in enumerate(candidate):
            tot_distance += distance(route, distances)

        fitness.append(tot_distance)

    return fitness

def main(debugMode):
  start = default_timer()

  data = DataProblem(debugMode)

  prng = Random()
  prng.seed(time())

  problem = inspyred.benchmarks.TSP(data.distances)
  ea = inspyred.ec.EvolutionaryComputation(prng)
  ea.selector = inspyred.ec.selectors.tournament_selection
  ea.variator = [custom_partially_matched_crossover, custom_inversion_mutation]
  ea.replacer = inspyred.ec.replacers.generational_replacement
  ea.terminator = inspyred.ec.terminators.generation_termination
  final_pop = ea.evolve(generator=generator,
                        bounder=problem.bounder,
                        maximize=False,
                        evaluator=inspyred.ec.evaluators.parallel_evaluation_mp,
                        mp_evaluator=evaluator, 
                        pop_size=100,
                        data=data,
                        max_generations=100000,
                        tournament_size=5,
                        num_selected=100,
                        num_elites=1)

  best = max(ea.population)
  print('Best Solution: {0}: {1}'.format(str(best.candidate), best.fitness))
  duration = default_timer() - start
  print(duration / 60)
  return ea


if __name__ == '__main__':

  try:
    fileLocation = sys.argv[1]
    timeOfDay = sys.argv[2]
    debugMode = False
  except:
    debugMode = True
    timeOfDay = 'morning'

  main(debugMode)
```

The mp_evaluator enables multiprocessing and uses the following method:

```
def parallel_evaluation_mp(candidates, args):

    import time
    import multiprocessing

    nprocs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    start = time.time()
    try:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nprocs)
        results = [pool.apply_async(evaluator, ([c], pickled_args)) for c in candidates]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return [r.get()[0] for r in results]
    except (OSError, RuntimeError) as e:
        logger.error('failed parallel_evaluation_mp: {0}'.format(str(e)))
        raise
    else:
        end = time.time()
        logger.debug('completed parallel_evaluation_mp in {0} seconds'.format(end - start))
```

However when I look in my activity monitor I only see about 85% of 1 processor being used with 4 threads. The code executes actually faster on 1 processor without the multiprocessor enabled.

But why is it using 4 threads instead of 4 processors in case of a quad-core machine?

Comment: The GIL, you can run on multiple processors with Dask

Comment: @Wade GIL is not relevant to `multiprocessing`. It is very possible to use the standard library to achieve true parallel processing across a multi core cpu.

Comment: As a rule of habit you should never start a child process outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` context. This often solves a myriad of strange bugs.

Comment: thanks @Aaron for having a look. I have updated the question with a bigger slice of the code.

Comment: Could you try to trim this down to a more minimal example where you perhaps minimize the code going into formatting your args, and provide an example `evaluator` function that just does some dummy work: `time.sleep()` for example. How you create the pool and pass work in and out of it are more important than all the genetic algo stuff.

Comment: Is the genetic algorithm relevant to the issue at hand? Could you remove that code for clarification purposes?

Comment: @Aaron I minimised it a bit. the evaluator is pretty simple. it just calculates the the fitness of a possible candidate. (im addressing a vehicle routing problem). so its just the total distance of all routes.

Comment: @yorodm its relevant to some extend. the ea.evolve comes from the library. as a matter of fact, the entire example comes straight from the docs: https://pythonhosted.org/inspyred/examples.html#the-multiprocessing-module

Comment: Change `evaluator` to be a function like `def evaluator(*args): while True: pass`, remove all code that is not directly used. If the issue does not appear again it's the library that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: @Bakuriu you are right. when changing it to while True: pass, the cores are activated :). I wonder why?

Comment: Perhaps the actual evaluation is complete very fast so the additional processes don't stick around for very long, and you're just left with a bit of extra overhead, and whatever other slow operation that's actually taking up the majority of the time? It would seem a new pool is created and destroyed for every generation..

Comment: @Aaron hmm good point.. ill study on this. till now no luck

Comment: @apfz perhaps you can inject `logger.debug('hello from process: {}'.format(multiprocessing.current_process().pid))` into a few key locations to see if messages from more than one pid are logged. (or even just use `print`)